# When to use Component or Model in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Sometimes I get a hard time choosing between adding a certain piece of code in the component controller or the model in the CakePhp framework. The block of code is not dealing with an entry in the database, but still it's relevant to a certain Model. Whats the best practice here?

### Thanks

Yehia A.Salam

Comment: without a real piece of code (some example of what you are talking here) its hard to work with this question. being a little bit more concrete would be crucial for a "real" question and an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'll give you a few examples

- Any data processing should happen in a model. (fetching data, calculations, transformations, saving...)
- Stuff that deals with requests and responses goes usually into a component (like auth)
- Re-usable code that works with data should become a behavior (like slugs or tags, see the cakedc plugins)
- Code that does recurring tasks on output would go into a helper (recaptcha helper)

If you start reading [the book](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/index.html), the first page already starts to describe the basic differences between controllers, models and views.:

- Controllers handle requests, and help co-ordinate and prepare the response for the client. Read more about Controllers
- Views are the presentation layer in CakePHP. They convert the data fetched from Models, into the output format the client requested. Read more about Views
- Models are the heart of your application, they handle the validation, storage and retrieval of your data. Read more about Models

Understanding the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) also helps.

For an example that involves a component, behavior and helper take a look at the CakeDC [recaptcha plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/recaptcha/tree/2.0).

Comment: These are nice terms and you always try to follow them but let me say the whole MVC is ideal. In the real life practice there are cases when to solve something in the controller is more convenient and need less code than in the model (and sometimes the speed of the app is better). I usually use models as storing facility and there are general handling issues when using model callbacks is the best. But sometimes several controller need to work with the same model and calculate and prepare datas from the user input. In that case I usually do it in the controller. Each case need your decision.